# App Store update not working in Mac after upgrading to Sierra

Tags: software-update, macos

I have recently upgraded my Mac to Sierra. After upgrading AppStore update not working. It shows I have to update for apps Keynote, Pages, Numbers and GarageBand. But while I want to update those individually or all at once every time AppStore ask for the password. If I put correct password it ask the password again and again. If I put incorrect password it shows that password is incorrect.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's some things to try:

- Close and reopen App Store
- Reenter iCloud credentials in System Preferences
- Turn Mac off and back on

If none of those work, it might be an issue with Apple's servers, in which case you'll have to wait it out.